# How to find intelligently counterexamples for (dis)proofs about matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Let's say I'm asked to give a counterexample for a claim about matrices, such as

> The elementwise product of two positive semi-definite matrices is positive semi-definite.

It's easy enough to do some intelligent guess-and-checking with the help of a computer and find an answer in a few seconds.

But how do I do this in my head when I don't have a computer handy? I can't find a simple way. Either I have to pick the eigenvalues in the diagonal matrix $D$ and then somehow come up with a matrix $P$ to make $A = PDP^{-1}$ positive semi-definite, repeat this for another matrix, and *hope* that the result isn't PSD, or I have to pick a non-PSD $A$ directly (how?), repeat this for a second matrix, and then *hope* the result is not PSD.

Either way, I have to go through several matrix multiplications just to verify that the result is/isn't PSD, which is trivial for a computer but something that takes too long on a piece of paper.

Is there a better way?
Are there shortcuts I can take to avoid multiplying matrices in my head or on paper?

Comment: What do you mean by 'takes too long'? This is how people did it for centuries and still do it, at least those who do not see a more clever approach or cannot figure it out in their head (which applies to most of us...). Doing it that way, btw, will motivate you to think of a short cut...

Comment: @Thomas: By "too long" I mean I wouldn't be able to solve it in time on an exam (or if I did, then I would run short of time for the rest of the exam), so I figure there has to be a shortcut.

Comment: Your example is a true statement. You should give a false statement as an example.

Comment: @Peter: Are you sure? $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A^T$ are both PSD, but $B = A \circ A^T = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}$ is not PSD. ([Try plotting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Ex7.png) $z = x^T A^T x$, for example.)

Comment: Seems right. Wikipedia states that the hadamard product of matrices would have this property. If the author only allows symmetric matrices ?

Comment: @Peter: If it's assumed asymmetric then yes. For this question let's assume it's not. :)